# How to launch an application when Notification Received from flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a mobile app and I want to open a splash screen or open startup page when I receive a notification.

Currently, I am using the following code

```
static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(
      Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("_backgroundMessageHandler");
    _callBgHandler = 1;
    if (message.containsKey('data')) {
      // Handle data message
      final dynamic data = message['data'];
      print("_backgroundMessageHandler: ${data}");
      DeviceApps.openApp("com.example.my_flutter_app");
    }
     if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
      // Handle notification message
      final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
      print("_backgroundMessageHandler notification: ${notification}");
    }
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
```

and the following error displayed

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager
>   android.app.Activity.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference

The last one month tried but no luck. If anyone knows let me share the code from flutter dart language

But Button press event it will work.

```
 RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              DeviceApps.openApp("com.example.my_flutter_app");
            },
            child: Text("Open App")
        )
```

Default applications like a map, chrome, play store, email app, etc... All are open with no issue but the external app does not open notification background function.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?